# How to update docker container running on Amazon ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm very new to Amazon ECS, and I've written a task definition with 3 containers. One for my php application (main-server), second for node application (pubsub-server) and a redis container.

`main-server` and `pubsub-server` link to `redis` container. (Is this the best way to arrange the containers?)

The cluster runs well. However, I have an update to make in my `main-server`. I am able to push the updated image to Amazon ECR but my changes don't reflect on the cluster. Is there any additional step to perform to run the updated container on push?

I have tried deregistering the tasks and activating them back. But it doesn't seem to work.

Please let me know if I need to provide anymore details.

Comment: seems to me your question relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485031/ecs-service-automating-deploy-with-new-docker-image
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819201/how-to-ensure-to-update-docker-image-on-aws-ecs?rq=1

Comment: You don't update containers. You deploy an updated image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ECS Service - Automating deploy with new Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31485031/ecs-service-automating-deploy-with-new-docker-image)

Answer (score 2):

You need to force a new deployment.
From the AWS console, update the service definition and check the force new deployment checkbox on the first page, then skip to confirmation page.

From CLI:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster [cluster arn] --service [service arn] --force-new-deployment
```